# Is there a way to parse json, having circularity, with regex?

Tags: json, regex-lookarounds

I have a json column (FullText) in a really big sql table (MariaDB) and I need to query with regexp over it WITHOUT JSON_EXTRACT functions. 
Often the schema contains a property containing an array of similar schemas and I need to match ONLY properties of the first level.

I tried to match "title: \'Title1\'" is is before the first occurrence of "relatedArticles" with this regexp:

^.*?(title:\"Title1\").+?(?=relatedArticles)

but it matches also schemas present in relatedArticles array of other articles.

```
{
 id: 1,
 title: 'Title1',
 description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...',
 relatedArticles: [
   {
     id: 10,
     title: 'Title10',
     description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...10',
     relatedArticles: null
   },
   {
     id: 9,
     title: 'Title9',
     description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...9',
     relatedArticles: null
   }

 ]
},
{
 id: 17,
 title: 'Title17',
 description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...17',
 relatedArticles: [
   {
     id: 7,
     title: 'Title7',
     description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...7',
     relatedArticles: null
   },
   {
     id: 1,
     title: 'Title1',
     description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...',
     relatedArticles: null
   }
 ]
}
```

I need a regex to match any "property: 'value'" string in the first level of my json schema, returning "no match" if my string is matched other levels.

Comment: Why can't you use the JSON functions?  They probably _parse_ your JSON content, which is the correct thing to do.  Trying to use a regex here is the _incorrect_ thing to do.

Comment: I tried, but I have almost 4GB of table and it's really really heavy and slow. MariaDB has no native support for JSON field.
So I decided to try with a combination of FullText query and regex.

JSON_EXTRACT requires 20sec; FullText+regex less than a second.